# Does this equation hold with equality or only approximately

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $\lambda(s)$ be a "nice" function.

My question is, does it hold with equality (or only approximately) that:
\begin{equation}
1-\exp\left\{-\int_t^{t+dt}\lambda(s)ds\right\}
= \lambda(t)dt
\end{equation}
for arbitrarily small $dt$?

If so, I would be happy to see the proof.

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on how you define equality. It is true to infinite accuracy since it implies $$\lambda(t+\mathrm dt)-\lambda(t)=0.$$ Since $\lambda$ is nice (which includes being continuous, presumably), then this is true to infinite accuracy.

Comment: OK, thanks.
Do you have the possibility to share the proof? Thanks.

Comment: Rearrange, take logarithms and differentiate.